# Solidity event n emit syntex

Tags: events, solidity, emit

Hope doing well

I want to do the following activities in solidity code below but dont know how, please advise.
Thanks with regards
Syed

QUERY:_

Emit an event ScoreChanged with two arguments: int amount (equal to the value that was sent) and bool direction (true for up function and false for down)

Emit an event GameEnded after gameOver is switched to true

CODE:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TugOfWar {

    int public score = 0;
    int constant endAt = 1 ether;
    bool public gameOver = false;

    function up() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(!gameOver);

        int value = int(msg.value);
        score += value;

        checkIfGameOver();
    }

        function down() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(!gameOver);

        int value = int(msg.value);
        score -= value;

        checkIfGameOver();
    }
        function checkIfGameOver() internal {
        if(score >= endAt || score <= endAt * -1) {
            gameOver = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define events in the contract by:

```
event ScoreChanged(uint amount, bool up);
event GameEnded(bool up); // where 'up' indicates which side won.
```

to emit the events you write:

```
emit ScoreChanged(msg.value, true); // where the second argument indicates the direction
```

you could to this right after you increment or decrement the score.

and when the game has ended:

```
emit GameEnded(true); // where the argument indicates which side has won.
```